# Scraping data from href

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to get the postcodes for DFS, for that i tried getting the href for each shop and then click on it, the next page has shop location from which i can get the postal code, but i am able to get things working, Where am i going wrong?
I tried getting upper level attribute first `td.searchResults` and then for each of them i am trying to click on `href with title DFS` and after clicking getting the postalCode. Eventually iterate for all three pages.
 If there is a better way to do it let me know.

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://www.localstore.co.uk/stores/75061/dfs/')
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    listings = soup.select('td.searchResults')
    for l in listings:
         while True:      
              driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*='DFS']").click()
              shops= {}
              #info = soup.find('span', itemprop='postalCode').contents
              html = driver.page_source
              soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
              info = soup.find(itemprop="postalCode").get_text()
              shops.append(info)
```

Update:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.localstore.co.uk/stores/75061/dfs/')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
listings = soup.select('td.searchResults')

for l in listings:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*='DFS']").click()
    shops = []
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    info = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"itemprop": "postalCode"})
    for m in info:
        if m:
           m_text = m.get_text()
           shops.append(m_text)
    print (shops)
```

Comment: what things are working? and what is going wrong?

Comment: while loop is not working, i am able to get postcode for just 1st href data, other href(links) are not getting clicked and thus i am unable to get postcodes for other href's links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after playing with this for a little while, I don't think the best way to do this is with selenium. It would require using `driver.back()` and waiting for elements to re-appear, and a whole mess of other stuff. I was able to get what you want using just `requests`, `re` and `bs4`. `re` is included in the Python standard library and if you haven't installed `requests`, you can do it with pip as follows: `pip install requests`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.localstore.co.uk'
url = 'http://www.localstore.co.uk/stores/75061/dfs/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)

shops = []

links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('.*\/store\/.*'))

for l in links:
    full_link = base_url + l['href']
    town = l['title'].split(',')[1].strip()
    res = requests.get(full_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    info = soup.find('span', attrs={"itemprop": "postalCode"})
    postalcode = info.text
    shops.append(dict(town_name=town, postal_code=postalcode))

print shops
```

Comment: Great.. This works perfectly.. Thanks for figuring this out, learnt a lot from this approach

Comment: i don't think its a good idea to do the whole coding thing. you can give idea or code snippet and explain why that should work and what's wrong with OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems. You are using an infinite loop without breaking condition. Also `shops= {}` is a `dict` but you are using `append` method on it.
Instead of using `selenium` you can use [python-requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).

But In your code you can do something like this,

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.localstore.co.uk/stores/75061/dfs/')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
listings = soup.select('td.searchResults')

for l in listings:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*='DFS']").click()
    shops = []
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    info = soup.find('span', attrs={"itemprop": "postalCode"})
    if info:
        info_text = info.get_text()
        shops.append(info_text)
    print shops
```

In Beautifulsoup you can find a tag by it's attribute like this:

```
soup.find('span', attrs={"itemprop": "postalCode"})
```

also if it doesn't find anything, it will return `None` and `.get_text()` method on it will raise `AttributeError`. So check first before applying `.get_text()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, this looks clean , but this kis always getting the postalcode for the top href, and not for all href's, for example I am getting just for edenburg, and it the postal code is repeating itself  and not for others. any help in this regard?

Comment: yes, sure. this is because of `soup.find()` method. `find()` will return only the first one. use `soup.find_all()`. it will return a list and then iterate over the list. i hope you can do it.

Comment: somehow i am unable to figure out the iteration,it(soup.find_all)still gives me just for 1st href, sorry if you could help me fix this.

Comment: `for l in listings:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title*='DFS']").click()
    shops = []
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    info = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"itemprop": "postalCode"})
    for m in info:
        if m:
           m_text = m.get_text()
           shops.append(m_text)
    print (shops)`

Comment: i don't understand why you are trying to edit my answer. I clearly told you to edit your question.

Comment: You should update your question with code snippets, not paste them in a comment

Comment: As per what I can infer seeing the scrapper behavior,  soup functions well for the final page, but the click is always happening for the first href,  that's why I am getting all duplicate postcodes.  Any way to fix this?