# Scraping a page + click on its href and takes hrefs data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I'm trying to scrap a page and take it's hrefs data which are in  tag, but i can't get result. This is an assignment for my school. 
May someone help me please to resolve this issue?

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

for i in range (1,5):
    base_url = 'https://www.leboncoin.fr/locations'
    url = 'https://www.leboncoin.fr/locations/1152669519.htm?ca=22_s'
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)

    locations = []

    links = soup.find_all(['li','a'], href=re.compile('.*\/locations\/+(i)+'))

    for l in links:
        full_link = base_url + l['href']
        titre = l[['li', 'section', 'h2']].strip()
        res = requests.get(full_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
        loyer = soup.find(['h2','span'], attrs={"class": "value\^((?![A-Z]).)*$"})
        loyers = loyer.text
        ville = soup.find(['h2','span'], attrs={"class": "value", "itemprop": "adresse"})
        villes = ville.text
        surface = soup.find(['h2','span'], attrs={"class": "clearfix", "calss": "value"})
        surfaces = surface.text
        description = soup.find('p', attrs={"class": "value", "itemprop": "description"})
        descriptions = description.text
        shops.append(titre, loyers, villes, surfaces, descriptions)

    print(locations)
```

I got this like result:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You never append anything to `locations` at any point in your code, why shouldn't it be blank when you print it?

Comment: Yeah I forgot to modify this, because I took an issue that was solved before and adapted it for my case.
[Scraping data from href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845391/scraping-data-from-href)
but i don't get any result.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say, you don't get any result because you never add anything to `locations`. If you never add anything to it, it doesn't matter how much other code you copy from other places, `locations` will still be empty. What do you expect `locations` to have in it?

Comment: I want that locations contain `locations.append(shops)`
But even with the code below proposed by another person I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defines shops anywhere, I am assuming that you want a dictionary. So for that do this:

```
for l in links:
    shops = {}
    full_link = base_url + l['href']
    shops['titre'] = l[['li', 'section', 'h2']].strip()
    res = requests.get(full_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    loyer = soup.find(['h2','span'], attrs={"class": "value\^((?![A-Z]).)*$"})
    shops['loyers'] = loyer.text
    ville = soup.find(['h2','span'], attrs={"class": "value", "itemprop": "adresse"})
    shops['villes'] = ville.text
    surface = soup.find(['h2','span'], attrs={"class": "clearfix", "calss": "value"})
    shops['surfaces'] = surface.text
    description = soup.find('p', attrs={"class": "value", "itemprop": "description"})
    shops['descriptions'] = description.text
    locations.append(shops)

print(locations)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but even with your code i got the same result, this time just one

    []
    
Do you have any idea about the problem ?
I'm new in this filed, this is why.

Comment: First of all, you are trying to find links on this page: https://www.leboncoin.fr/locations/1152669519.htm?ca=22_s instead of this: https://www.leboncoin.fr/locations.